# Summing up more than two dataframes with the same indexes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition

I want to add values of 4 Dataframes with the same indexes in Pandas. If there are two dataframes, df1 and df2, we may write:

```
df1.add(df2)
```

and for 3 dataframes:

```
df3.add(df2.add(df1))
```

I wonder if there is a more general way to do so in Python.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `sum`

```
sum([df1, df2, df3, df4])
```

**Option 2**
Use `reduce`

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(pd.DataFrame.add, [df1, df2, df3, df4])
```

**Option 3**
Use `pd.concat` and `pd.DataFrame.sum` with `level=1`
This only works if there is a single level to the dataframe indices.  We've have to get a little more cute to make it work.  I recommend the other options.

```
pd.concat(dict(enumerate([df1, df2, df3, df4]))).sum(level=1)
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, -1], [complex(0, 1), complex(0, -1)]])
df1, df2, df3, df4 = [df] * 4
```

**Demo**

```
sum([df1, df2, df3, df4])

        0        1
0  (4+0j)  (-4+0j)
1      4j      -4j
```

---

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(pd.DataFrame.add, [df1, df2, df3, df4])

        0        1
0  (4+0j)  (-4+0j)
1      4j      -4j
```

---

```
pd.concat(dict(enumerate([df1, df2, df3, df4]))).sum(level=1)

        0        1
0  (4+0j)  (-4+0j)
1      4j      -4j
```

---

**Timing**

*small data*

```
%timeit sum([df1, df2, df3, df4])
%timeit reduce(pd.DataFrame.add, [df1, df2, df3, df4])
%timeit pd.concat(dict(enumerate([df1, df2, df3, df4]))).sum(level=1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 591 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 456 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.61 ms per loop
```

*larger data*

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, -1], [complex(0, 1), complex(0, -1)]])
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
df = pd.concat([df] * 100, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df1, df2, df3, df4 = [df] * 4

%timeit sum([df1, df2, df3, df4])
%timeit reduce(pd.DataFrame.add, [df1, df2, df3, df4])
%timeit pd.concat(dict(enumerate([df1, df2, df3, df4]))).sum(level=1)

100 loops, best of 3: 3.94 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.9 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 1min per loop
```

Comment: interesting that plain `sum` just works here +1, if the number of dfs isn't prohibitive, you could just do `df1 + df2 + df3 + df4` as an alternative

Comment: It invokes the `__add__` method on the underlying object... so it just works

Comment: Great Answer! A note to Option 2: If you only get a lot NaN values, you need to define a fill_value: reduce(lambda x, y: pd.DataFrame.add(x, y, fill_value=0), [df1, df2, df3])